# pointer targets in passing argument of xxx differ in signedness

Tags: c, pointers

I go compile error: `"pointer targets in passing argument 4 of xxx differ in signedness [-Werror=pointer-sign]"` since in my project compile warning is treated as error.
But what confuse me is that the following pseudo code get warning on func2 but not func1:

```
func1(int  var1);

func2(int* var2);

my_func()
{

    unsigned int myVar1 = xxx;
    unsigned int* pMyVar2 = ooo;

    func1(myVar1);   //no warning
    func2(pMyVar2);  //warning
}
```

I thought there should also have warning for func1 since differ signedness argument is used, but only func2 get warning. Does it means pass pointer of differ signedness is more dangerous than pass value of differ signedness into function?
Or is it simply configured seperately by compile option?

Comment: Many warnings are enabled only when the thing they warn about is more likely than not to be an actual error and not just a common sloppy pattern. The compiler could warn you about a magnitude more potential problems, but this would lead to alarm fatigue and just make people disable warnings.

Comment: `pseudo code get warning on func2 but not func2:`...wait, what?

Comment: All integral types are implicitly convertible to each other. Pointers to different integral types are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`int *` & `unsigned int *` are two different pointer types that are **not** compatible.

You have to explicitly cast pointer to be possible convert him to the other one.

```
func2((int*)pMyVar2);
```

---

While non-pointer `int` and `unsigned int`

From C standard [c99](/questions/tagged/c99) **6.3.1.3**

> When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type
>   other than _Bool, if the value can be represented by the new type, it
>   is unchanged.
>
> Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by
>   repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that
>   can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of
>   the new type.
>
> Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented
>   in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an
>   implementation-defined signal is raised.